# Cross reference a figure from another frame

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, citing

I have a figure in one frame and couple of frames later, I need to reference the figure. When I call `\ref`, it just prints `??` in the beamer presentation. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{some_fig.eps}
\caption{A figure}
\label{ref1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Something here.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
I reference the figure as Fig.\ref{ref1}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Like I mentioned, I get the following output on the third slide:
`I reference the figure as Fig.??.`

Why is referencing across slides not working? Thanks.

Comment: For me your MWE compiles fine (after changing ``some_fig.eps`` to ``example-image``) and shows the reference on the third slide. Did you compile at least twice?

Comment: @Vincent thanks. Yes I did compile 2 and more number of times

Comment: @Vincent I also get the error `Reference \`ref1' on page 3 undefined on input line xx.`

Comment: How do you compile the document? Maybe for some reason the auxiliary files are removed between runs? Also: does it work when you put the label and the reference on the same slide?

Comment: @Marijn I use `pdfLaTeX` to compile. Checked, you're right, same slide referencing doesn't work too. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @learner and which editor/environment do you use? Do you compile from the terminal, or do you have some LaTeX IDE such as TeXstudio, or maybe a plugin for a simple editor, or an online editor such as Overleaf? Do you use a compile tool such as `latexmk` or `arara` or not? I'm asking these questions to try to find out if the auxiliary file (where the information about references and labels is stored between runs) is deleted or not. So I can also ask directly: is there an auxiliary file present after the first run? What is the content of this file for a very simple document with [...]

Comment: @Marijn I am sorry for the first response. I use Texmaker. Yes there's an auxiliary file present after every run

Comment: one slide and one label/ref combination? Another (a bit less likely) possibility is that there is some kind of invisible Unicode character or one of the visible characters looks the same but is actually different, you can test this by writing a new ref/label pair directly on the keyboard without copying.

Comment: Or maybe the `aux` file is created correctly after a run, but is deleted at the start of a new run? What is listed in Options-Configure TexMaker at the pdfLaTeX entry? Also, does it work for normal documents (with documentclass article), or is the issue only with `beamer`?

Comment: @Marijn in the pdfLaTeX entry I have `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. It worked fine for an article. Haven't tried others, but `beamer` definetely has a problem

Comment: Ok, that all looks good, can you post the contents of the `aux` file in your question?